# How do children learn to identify different languages?

Tags: reference-request, language-acquisition, bilingualism

A child can be raised in a sufficiently bilingual context that they learn two languages simultaneously, e.g. English & Spanish, Norwegian and Saami. The end product is that they have two linguistic systems. The part that I'm interested in is, how do children sort out which words (or other linguistic objects like rules) are in language A versus language B? In particular, at the earliest stages of acquisition. I assume there is research on the topic, and I am looking for a few peer-reviewed state of the art type published articles in this area (please no Wiki pages or anecdotes).

Comment: Pity that you are not interested in "anecdotes". Otherwise I would offer you this professional linguist's observation of his bilingual (Arabic-English) grandchildren.

Comment: obviously children are primed by the speaker who embodies the language. you might as well consider a monolingual context, but multilingual is actually *easier*. For whom though?

Comment: @fdb I would be interested. Looks like 'this' (or 'observation') was supposed to be a link? They are not, though.